# Do I need to namespace my JavaScript code if it's in an <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, namespaces

If I write some JavaScript that runs in an <iframe> (which is dynamically created and added to the DOM with JavaScript, if that matters), is it isolated from the global namespace of its parent page, or are conflicts still possible?

I did some Googling and came across this page, but I can't really make sense of what he's doing here, or if it applies to exactly what I'm trying to determine/accomplish.

http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/sandbox/

I'm creating a widget that will live on unknown host pages; it's a <script> that inserts an <iframe> on the page, then creates a document that loads some external scripts and inserts that document into the dynamically created <iframe>.

Basically, I just want to avoid conflicts with any global variables on the host page; I don't want any JavaScripts that I write or load in the <iframe> to conflict with anything on the host page.

If using an <iframe> doesn't automatically protect me, can anyone recommend an approach that will isolate any <script>s running in the <iframe>?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the namespace of each is separated, it should be fine. Consider the following

Host page JavaScript:

```
Foo = {};
Foo.bar = function(){ alert('hi!');}
```

Now the iframe JavaScript:

```
Foo = {};
Foo.bar = function(){ alert('yo!');}
```

For the iframe to talk to the parent, it would have to do something like this

```
window.parent.Foo.bar(); //Alerts 'hi!'
Foo.bar(); //Alerts 'yo!'
```

For the host page to see the frame, it would have to do this:

```
window.frames['nameOfFrame'].contentWindow.Foo.bar(); //Alerts 'yo!'
Foo.bar(); //Alerts 'hi!'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, anything in the iFrame should be out of scope from the rest of the page.  However, you can refrence the main page code by using `parent`.

```
var foo

<iframe>
var bar = parent.foo;
</iframe>
```

*I know this is not how the iframe looks.  Just trying to simplify.*

Answer (score 1):

Using normally, the scripts in iframe and in the main window are both isolated from each other.

**main.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function ale(){alert('test');}
</script>
<iframe src="fr.html"></iframe>

</body></html>
```

**fr.html**:

```
<input type="button" onclick="ale();" />
```

Notice that when you open main.html and click on the button in the iframe, an Javascript error saying that ale(); is not defined will be generated. This is because they are 2 seperate documents.

However, you will be able to access the parent frame's document object from the iframe using the `window.parent` node. e.g. `window.parent.getElementById('mainform')`

**Summary**
There is no need to namespace your code in the iframe.

Comment: Thanks, Mauris! That's what I had suspected, but I wanted to be sure there wasn't something I was missing or had misunderstood.